# Enhance performance of method

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, plinq

how can the following method perform better?

First some background information:

A mapping between form and used logics (on a deeper layer) is put in a dictionary CtrlLogicMapping.

A control can have multiple logics (e.g. for different controls on a form).

In certain cases it is necessary to know wether an object is already inuse in one (independend which) control logics.

Each logic can have one or more mapped objectscopes, which are from a third party vendor and contain the information about objects mapped to db.

If an object is used, therefore aLogic.ObjectScope.IsUsed(ObjectID) could return true or false.

I want a method which asked every existing ObjectScope once wether the object is in it, and as soon as an objectscope has the object true should be returned (other objectscopes do no longer need to be processed. An ObjectScope can be in multiple Logics.

Not every form needs to have logics (therefore the list can be null or empty) and not every logic needs an objectscope (also there the list can be null or empty).

The InUse method is somethign which can take awhile (InUse in tests took between 60 and 140 ms).

So I want to avoid calling of InUse as much as possible, and maybe parallize it as much as possible.

The iterative solution:

```
internal bool InUse (string ID_in){

        List<string> checked = new List<string>();

        if (null != frmLogicMapping && 0 < frmLogicMapping.Count)
        {
            foreach (List<Logic> logics in frmLogicMapping.Values)
            {
                if (null != logics && 0 < logics.Count)
                {
                    foreach (Logic aLogic in logics)
                    {
                        if (null != aLogic.ObjectScope)
                        {
                            if (!checked.Contains(aLogic.ObjectScope.ID)) 
                            {
                                // can take up to 140 ms
                                if (aLogic.ObjectScope.InUse(ID_in)) 
                                    return true;
                                checkeded.Add(aLogic.ObjectScope.ID);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
   }
```

Is there a way to paralize it with the stop criteria that InUse==true should immediatly return true and other processing should not report anything?

Or coudl it also be written somehow in PLINQ ? How can null values be handled in PLINQ? Or would normal LINQ be a better choice? (even how to handle the null values?)

What i wanted to do was something like

```
        if (null != frmLogicMapping&& 0 < frmLogicMapping.Count)
        {
            var objectscopes = frmLogicMapping.Values
                .Where(logics != null && logics.Count > 0)
                .SelectMany(logic => logic.ObjectScope)
                .Where(logic.ObjectScope!= null).ToList();

            bool returnValue = false;
            Parallel.ForEach(objectscopes, objectScope=>
            {
                if (objectScope.IsDirtyObject(objectID))
                {
                    returnValue  = true;
                }
            });
            return returnValue  ;
        }
```

but somehow i mix up the linq statement ... and i also don't know how to immediate return from parallel foreach, or how to mark the returnvalue as volatile

Thanxs, Offler

---

Solution so far: thanx to Stephen Borg

```
 if (null != objectScopes && 0 < objectScopes .Count)
        {
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>[] tasks = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>[objectScopes.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < objectScope.Count; i++)
            {
                int temp= i;
                tasks[temp] = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return objectScopes[temp].InUse(ID_in); }
                    , System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }

            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            if (tasks.Any(x => x.Result == true))
            {
                return true;
            }
        } 

        return false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to create a method which validates the List list, and use the System.Threading.Tasks.Task, view here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx.

You can do something similar to this, structure wise :

```
            Func DummyMethod = () =>{
                return true;
            };

            // Create list of tasks
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task[] tasks = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task[2];

            // First task
            var firstTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DummyMethod(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            tasks[0] = firstTask;

            // Second task
            var secondTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DummyMethod(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            tasks[1] = secondTask;

            // Launch all
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            if (tasks.Any(x => x.Result)) { 
                Console.Write("In use!");
            }
```

In you case you would need to loop the task results and check if any of the returned values are true. The gain would be that all the lists will be run at once, on seperate threads.

Comment: If i understand you correctly i would first build a list of objectscopes and then create for each objectscope a task (in a for loop?) and afterwards call the results of every task (again for?). If i would use your code, i could not access task.Result. if (tasks[i].Result == true) <- no definition for result / firstTask.Result <- contains definition for Result?

Comment: When looking at the code posted, you are storing in a boolean, if in use or not. Why not create a variable before the list of tasks, and in the method, you would convert the boolean to true if found? I think it would still perform better given the task split into separate threads.

Comment: I updated my answer, to show you how to obtain the result from the tasks.

Comment: The generic "<", and ">" are not being displayed after I submitted my answer, no sure why. I am going to try here now, the function DummyMethod is as follows : Func<bool> DummyMethod = () =>{
                return true;
            };

Comment: And the creation of the task list, is as follows aswell : System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>[] tasks = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>[2];

Comment: The problem was that "tasks[i]).Result == true" was not possible. An additional cast is needed to : (System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>)tasks[i]).Result == true . Also tasks.Any(x => x.Result -Y System.Threading.Task does not contain a Definition for Result

Comment: Yes it is possible, if the list of tasks is created in this way : System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>[].

Comment: thank you, already changed it in the way (see original post). Still used an anonymous method. Still wonder if a break is possible so that the result is given as soon as the first turn to true (or every task is equal to false)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31515/discussion-between-stephen-borg-and-offler)